# How to attach file using Nodemailer in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email, attachment

I am using React with Nodemailer to send emails from a user input form, the user should be able to attach a file (a PDF for example) through the form and the content of the form will be sent as an email using Nodemailer. My issue comes with not knowing how to attach the file to the email. [Here](https://nodemailer.com/message/attachments/) is a list and examples of properties that can be used using Nodemailer. What properties can I extract from the object inputted through the file input to the `event.target.files` to use to attach to the email, can I get the path of the inputted file for example?

Code:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

const handleSubmit = async(e) => {
e.preventDefault();

try {
  await axios.post("http://localhost:4000/send_form", { file });
}
catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
}

return (
  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <input
      type="file"
      onChange={(e) => setFile(e.target.files[0])}
      required/>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
  </form>
);
```

Server:

```
app.post("/send_form", cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let { file } = req.body;

  await transport.sendMail({
    from: "from@sender.com",
    to: "to@receiver.com",
    subject: "Subject",
    html: `<h1>Hello</h1>`,
    attachments: [{
      filename: "",
      path: ""
    }]
  })
});
```

Comment: You've probably got at least three different problems here. (1) That isn't how you upload files with axios. (2) That isn't how you handle uploaded files in express. (3) Whatever the problem with nodemailer is

Comment: What specifically am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+how+do+I+upload+files+with+axios

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+express.js+handle+file+uploads

Comment: you can change the attachment into buffer and send it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need axios to upload the file, just POST it as [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) with the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch).

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('myfile', file);

  fetch('http://localhost:4000/upload', {
    method: 'POST', body: fd
  }).catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

If you have other data to submit along with your image it can also be append to the `FormData` object.

```
fd.append('name', 'Joe');
fd.append('age', 40);
// etc...
```

Or, you can simply capture all fields from any [`HTMLFormElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement). Just make sure to set the `enctype` attribute to be `multipart/form-data`.

```
let form = document.querySelector('#your-form');
let fd = new FormData(form);
```

Then, on the server you can use the [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) middleware to stream the file buffer to the nodemailer attachment:

```
import express from 'express';
import multer from 'multer';
import transport from './your_app.js'

const app = express();

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.memoryStorage()
});

app.post('/upload', upload.single('myfile'), (req, res) => {
  transport.sendMail({
    from: "from@sender.com",
    to: "to@receiver.com",
    subject: "Subject",
    html: `<h1>Hello</h1>`,
    attachments: [{
      filename: req.file.originalname,
      content: req.file.buffer
    }]
  })
});

app.listen(4000);
```

If you have other [middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.application) you need to use on this route, they can be passed in as an array:

```
import cors from 'cors';

let middleware = [
  cors(),
  upload.single('myfile')
];

app.post('/upload', middleware, handler);
```

Note that the key used in the following two statements must match. This key corresponds to the `name` attribute of the file input.

> In `handleSubmit()` :
>
> ```
> fd.append('myfile', file);
> ```
>
> In `app.post()` :
>
> ```
> upload.single('myfile')
> ```

Multer also allows for multiple file uploads if needed. You can either  capture several files from a single input with the [`multiple`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#multiple)  attribute:

```
upload.array('myfile', 3)
```

Or you could use several file inputs:

```
upload.fields([
  { name: 'myfile', maxCount: 1 },
  { name: 'another-file', maxCount: 8 }
])
```

If you do this, you will need to access the uploaded file data from the `req.files` property instead of the singular `req.file`.

The rest of your form data will be available in the `req.body` object:

```
req.body.name == 'Joe'
req.body.age == 40;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try this solution, but a question first, what if I have multiple values sent to the server from my form, do I still retrieve them in the parameters of the `app.post()` method? How would I go about doing this, do I use `upload.single("")` for every value, or is there a different way?

Comment: Also you removed the `cors()` method call from your `app.post()` parameter.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address the points made in your comments.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the edit and for the help, I tried your middleware array solution, however I am now getting the Cross-origin request blocked, are you sure it should work like this? Or may I be doing something incorrectly?

Comment: Passing in the middleware as an array [should definitely work](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3237). Did you remember to `import cors from 'cors'` first?

Comment: I just tried it again without changing anything and weirdly enough it worked, perhaps the server was not running.

Comment: Thank you my friend for your help and patience, appreciate it greatly!

Comment:  Happy to help! The rep boost is worth the extra effort. Good luck with the rest of your project.